# Unable to modify FD epoll: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, process, ros

Writing a C++ code (linux OS) - i have a program in which I am trying to execute another launch file (ROS) by using a system call.
Code:

```
int NodeletLauncher::startNode(std::string nodeName, std::string launchFile)
{
    std::string command_call = " roslaunch " + nodeName + " " + launchFile + " &";
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {
        case -1: //error
            ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Fork failed");
            break;
        case 0: //child process
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("Starting node: " << nodeName);
            system(command_call.c_str());
            mProcList[nodeName] = getpid();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am able to run it, but getting the following error:

> [ERROR] [1525469227.289615557]: Unable to modify FD epoll: No such
>   file or directory [ERROR] [1525469227.289675313]: Unable to remove FD
>   to epoll: No such file or directory

what does it mean? 
Is there a better way to start the program and not using a system call with '&' at the end? (add '&' in-order not to block the the parent proc).

Thank you!

Comment: You should use [Boost.Process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/process.html) ;-)